# javascript while loop problem,break doesn't stop the loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, break

I built a simple number guessing game with javascript.
After the computer guess the correct answer it should break the loop.
What I am wondering is that even though I break the loop at Line 18 
It still execute the code on Line 20(console.log(text)).
The funny thing is that after the break. Only console.log() get executed,L21 & L22 don't do anything,which they are supposed to be that way.
Can't really figure out why. I hope I make the question clear!

Executes last `console.log()` in [repl example](https://repl.it/@windate3411/while-loop-test)

But doesn't in the below snippet (the exact same code)..

```js
let answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
// start coding
console.log('Answer is ' + answer)
let max = 100
let min = 0
let guess = Math.floor((max + min) / 2)
let i = 1
while (true){
  let text = `#${i}: computer guess ${guess}.`
  if (guess > answer){
    text += 'TOO BIG!'
    max = guess
  } else if (guess < answer){
    text += 'TOO Small!'
    min = guess
  } else{
    text += 'win!'
    break
  }
  console.log(text)
  guess = Math.floor((max + min) / 2)
  i++
}
```

Comment: To add an interesting piece to this, if you add a `console.log()` statement after the `while` loop, it works as expected

Comment: @mhodges  thank you so much for rephrasing my question! I'm sorry for the trouble I've caused.

Comment: This looks to work as expected. It just does not print "win!" because you break out of the loop before you console.log the text

Comment: on snippet  it works as expected . what confuses me the most is that on Repl it works a bit differently

Comment: @DannyWang Check out my answer, I think it's what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that because the REPL tool tries to display a return value for the code you run, it's using the last value before the code exits, which is `text += "win!"`. **So it's not actually executing your `console.log(text)`, it just looks like it is.**

For example, if you change your code to the following, the REPL tool spits out a number (the value of `i` before the postfix). Because it's the last value it saw before the `while` loop exited.

[REPL example](https://repl.it/repls/NiftyInexperiencedSequences) showing a different "return" value, logging as expected

```js
let answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
// start coding
console.log('Answer is ' + answer)
let max = 100
let min = 0
let guess = Math.floor((max + min) / 2)
let i = 1
while (guess !== answer){
  let text = `#${i}: computer guess ${guess}.`
  if (guess > answer){
    text += 'TOO BIG!'
    max = guess
  } else if (guess < answer){
    text += 'TOO Small!'
    min = guess
  }
  console.log(text)
  guess = Math.floor((max + min) / 2)
  i++
}

// console.log(`#${i}: computer guess ${guess}. Win!`);
```

This is not normal JS behavior, and should be taken with a grain of salt when reading "return" values in the REPL tool.Hope this helps!

Comment: It makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much!

Comment: @DannyWang No problem, glad I could help! This was definitely a strange issue!!